# Custom Table of Contents Style with Horizontal Rules

Tags: pdftex, etoc

I'm trying to reproduce a custom-designed ToC (image below) with horizontal rules under the end of each chapter. I'm new to LaTeX, and not sure if something like this is even possible. I've looked at the `tocloft` package, but don't think it has the capabilities to reproduce this. Any recommendations on how to achieve this? Thanks!

[image: custom table of contents design]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think it can be done with `titletoc`, a companion package of `titlesec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to build a good approximation with the package `etoc`

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[thin,medium]{josefin}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand{\NiceTOC}{%
    \begingroup% 
    \newlength{\tocleftmargin}    
    \setlength{\tocleftmargin}{4em} % left margin indent <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}   %
    {\etocsavedchaptertocline{\sffamily\color{SlateGray4}\hspace{\tocleftmargin}\etocname}{\etocpage}
    \vskip-0.5em%
        \dimen0\hsize%
        \advance\dimen0-\tocleftmargin%
        \moveright\tocleftmargin\vbox{{\color{SlateGray4}\hrule width\dimen0}}\vskip-1em%
    }{}%
    \etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily \color{SteelBlue3} \Huge  Contents}}
    {\vskip-0.2em\color{DeepSkyBlue3}\noindent\hspace*{\tocleftmargin}\rule{\dimen0}{2pt}}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup}

\begin{document}
        
    \NiceTOC
    
    \chapter*{Executive Summary}    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Executive Summary}%
    
    \chapter*{Assessment Scope}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Assessment Scope}%
    
    \chapter*{Methodology}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Methodology}%
    
    \chapter*{Attack Path Narrative}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Attack Path Narrative}%
    
    \chapter*{Risk Ratings}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Risk Ratings}%
    
    \chapter*{Issues Identified}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Issues Identified}%
    
    \chapter*{Appendix A: Engagement Cleanup}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A: Engagement Cleanup}%
    
    \chapter*{Appendix B: Brief Description}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix B: Brief Description}%
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with the `tocloft` package.

```
% toclinesprob.tex  SE 595297
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{color}

% length of rule below chapters
\newlength{\ruleit} \setlength{\ruleit}{\textwidth}
% put the rule after chapter page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\hspace{-2.5em}\mbox{}\\[0.5\baselineskip] 
\hspace*{-1.5em}\rule{\ruleit}{0.4pt}}
% change Contents font to blue
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\color{blue}\huge\bfseries}

% no \chapter, \section, etc numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\chapter{Second chapter}
% put this after last \chapter for thick blue line at the bottom of the ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\color{blue}\rule{\ruleit}{2pt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]